# How to click on the button with text as Search as per the html through Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to use Selenium to click a "Search" Button but I cant seem to locate it.

```
<div class="search">
            <input type="submit" title="Search" value="Search" class="spinner">
</div>
```

My code looks like this:

```
search_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("spinner")
search_button.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Any help would be much much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: have you tried locating with other locators like css selector,xpath? Also, are you getting any exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".spinner")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='search']/input")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @title='Search']")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='Search']")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='Search']")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Search']")

elementByXpath = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='search']")
elementByXpath.find_element_by_tag_name("input").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to invoke `click()` on the button with text as **Search** you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `click()`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='spinner' and @title='Search']").click()
  ```
- Using `submit()`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='spinner' and @title='Search']").submit()
  ```

Comment: OP's requirement is python, not java.

Comment: @theGuy  above code is valid for python. You can cross check in pycharm.

Comment: @Amit it is valid now, my comment was for his original answer before the edit.

Comment: @spak Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.